# Awk: for-loop with array of numbers

Tags: awk

How to use an array of numbers in a `for` loop with awk ?

I tried:

```
awk '{ for (i in [10, 12, 18]) print i }' myfile.txt
```

But I'm getting a **syntax error**.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: You added more code but still haven't provided the sample input and expected output necessary in any question to demonstrate your requirements and for us to copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operator works on arrays. The way to create an array from a list of numbers like `10 12 18` is to `split()` a string containing those numbers.

To have those numbers stored as values in an array `a[]` with indices `1` to `3`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"; split("10 12 18",a," ")}
     (FNR>2)  { for(j in a) { i=a[j]; k=$i OFS $(i+1); c[k]++; d[k] = i } }
     END{for (k in c) print d[k],k,c[k] }' myfile.txt
```

To have those numbers stored as indices of an array `b[]` with all values `0-or-null` (same as an uninitialized scalar variable):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"; split("10 12 18",a," "); for (j in a) b[a[j]]}
     (FNR>2)  { for(i in b) { k=$i OFS $(i+1); c[k]++; d[k] = i } }
     END{for (k in c) print d[k],k,c[k] }' myfile.txt
```

If you didn't want to create the array once up front for some reason (e.g. the list of numbers you want to split is created dynamically) then you could create it every time you need it, e.g.:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     (FNR>2)  { split("10 12 18",a," "); for(j in a) { i=a[j]; k=$i OFS $(i+1); c[k]++; d[k] = i } }
     END{for (k in c) print d[k],k,c[k] }' myfile.txt
```

but obviously creating the same array multiple times is less efficient than creating it once.

Comment: ok, so it's necessary to set it before in `BEGIN` statement, no way to use a list of numbers directly in the `for` parenthesis, right?

Comment: No and yes. You could do the `split()` repeatedly in the block where you want to use it but that'd be inefficient. Awk is a tiny but powerful language because it's providers will only provide constructs to do things that aren't easy to do with other existing constructs. In this case it's easy to do what you want the way I show using general constructs so there isn't some other slightly briefer construct just to do that specific thing. Without that mantra you end up with the language bloat some other tools suffer from.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to create the array on  the fly just where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

kinda made a very rough emulation of a `for-loop` that directly takes in a list without needing an extra function call prior to that to initialize it :

- it tries to be as flexible as possible regarding what the
  delimiter(s) might be, so

  ```
  foreach("[CA=MX=JP=FR=SG=AUS=N.Z.]")
  ```

  would actually also work.
- Despite being shown with the `gawk` profile below,
  and using the `PROCINFO` array, you don't need `gawk` for it to work :

  - it's functional on `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.9.9.6`, `gnu gawk 5.1.1`, and `macos x`
- just added a `Unicode UTF8` feature, which works regardless of what your locale setting is, or whether you're using `gawk` `mawk` or `nawk`

  - emojis work fine too
- that said, it **cannot** properly parse `CSV`, `XML`, or `JSON` inputs
  *(didn't have the time to make it that fancy)*

  ```
           list 1 ::  10
           list 1 ::  12
           list 1 ::  18.
           list 1 ::  27
           list 1 ::  36
           list 1 ::  pi
           list 1 ::  hubble
           list 1 ::  kelvins
           list 1 ::  euler
           list 1 ::  higgs
           list 1 ::  9.6

           list 2 ::  CA
           list 2 ::  MX
           list 2 ::  JP
           list 2 ::  FR
           list 2 ::  SG
           list 2 ::  AUS
           list 2 ::  N.Z.

   # gawk profile, created Mon May  9 22:06:03 2022

   # BEGIN rule(s)

   BEGIN {
   11      while (i = foreach("[10, 12, 18., 27, 36, pi, hubble, kelvins, euler, higgs, 9.6]")) {
   11          print "list 1 :: ", i
       }
    1      printf ("\n\n\n")
    7      while (i = foreach("[CA, MX, JP, FR, SG, AUS, N.Z., ]")) {
    7          print "list 2 :: ", i
       }
   }


   # Functions, listed alphabetically

   20  function foreach(_, __)
       {
   20      if (_=="") {
           return \
                PROCINFO["foreach", "_"] = \
                PROCINFO["foreach", "#"] = _
           }
   20      __ = "\032\016\024"

   20      if (_!= PROCINFO["foreach", "_"]) { # 2
    2      
               PROCINFO["foreach","_"]=_

    2          gsub("^[ \t]*[[<{(][ \t]*"\
                    "|[ \t]*[]>})][ \t]*$"\
                    "|\\300|\\301","",_)

               gsub("[^"(\
                           "\333\222"~"[^\333\222]"\
                         ? "\\200-\\277"\
                            "\\302-\\364"\
                         : ""       \
                         )"[:alnum:]"\
                                      \   
                           "\302\200""""-\337\277" \
                        "\340\240\200-\355\237\277"  \
                         "\356\200\200-\357\277\277"   \
                      "\360\220\200\200-\364\217\277\277"\
                                                 \
                                   ".\42\47@$&%+-]+",__,_)

               gsub("^"(__)"|"\
                       (__)"$","", _)

    2          PROCINFO["foreach","#"]=_
           }
   20      if ((_=PROCINFO["foreach","#"])=="") { # 2
    2          return _
           }
   18      sub((__) ".*$", "", _)
           sub("^[^"(__)"]+("(__)")?","",PROCINFO["foreach","#"])
   18      return _
       }

           list 2 ::  CA
           list 2 ::  MX
           list 2 ::  JP
           list 2 ::  FR
           list 2 ::  SG
           list 2 ::  눷
           list 2 ::  
           list 2 ::  N.Z.

    while(i = foreach("[CA=MX=JP=FR=SG=\353\210\267"\
                      "=\360\237\244\241=N.Z.]")) { 

        print "list 2 :: ", i
    }
  ```